# How to align HTML elements from bottom to top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to achieve a layout in HTML that aligns elements from bottom to top?

**Basic HTML structure:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**Desired result:**

[image: css layout from bottom to top]

Looking for CSS or JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with pure `CSS` using `Flexbox`. The key property is the `flex-wrap` which can be set to `wrap-reverse` to get your desired layout.

Demo:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-content: flex-start;
  /* demo */
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v4z38apL/1/

P.S Of course, you need to consider browser support and vendor-prefixes.